# Need help using python 2.7.1 to select and run various batch files based on user input

Tags: python, batch-file

all.  I am trying to use python 2.7.1 to run batch files based on what a user enters at the input prompt.  The problem I'm having is the batch files do not run.  I have been able to get a specific batch file to run from python if it is called from main() but cannot get python to select the file based on the input value.  My code is:

```
from subprocess import Popen


def results():
    Popen("results.txt")
    selection()

def buildinga():
    Popen("5463.bat")
    results()

def base():
    Popen("base.bat")
    results()

def selection():
    print "This tool will check the device status for the specified building."
    print "Type 'exit' to quit the program."
    selection.c = input("Please enter the device number: ")


    if selection.c == "001":
        base()

    if selection.c == "5463":
        buildinga()

    if selection.c == "exit":
        exit()



def main():
    selection()


main()
```

The way I can run a single batch file is:

```
from subprocess import Popen

def batchwriter():
    Popen("make.bat")

def main():
    batchwriter()

main()
```

This way does not allow me to select which batch file to run, only the one specified.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried to post this in comments but could not.  raw_input is working.  The batch file is being run and then the results file displays, however, errors are displayed, as well.  The errors don't seem to affect functionality because the results are correct.  I am getting the following output:

```
This tool will check the device status for the specified building.
Type 'exit' to quit the program.
Please enter the device number: 5463
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\cstat\ct.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "M:\cstat\ct.py", line 34, in main
    selection()
  File "M:\cstat\ct.py", line 26, in selection
    buildinga()
  File "M:\cstat\ct.py", line 10, in buildinga
    results()
  File "M:\cstat\ct.py", line 5, in results
    Popen("results.txt")
  File "C:\Utilities\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Utilities\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

M:\cstat>[ 12:11:36.63] 5463 is ONLINE
```

Comment: In your single batch file case, can you run either `base()` or `buildinga()` instead of `batchwriter()`?

Comment: try setting it up with some MVC... Its a really easy fix might want to try making this into classes.

Comment: Is it OK that `main` calls `selection`, `selection` calls for example `buildinga`, `buildinga` calls `results`, `results` call `selection` and the process loops? There may be problems with `call stack`.

Comment: What's the value of selection.c after the input? print that out and see...

Comment: Ok, changing from input to raw_input worked.  I got rid of the errors posted above by removing the results section.  I instead changed the batch file to echo the results in the command prompt window.  This will work for my purposes.  I cannot resolve my own question for another 6 hours since I am new to the site.  I thank everyone for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) istead of [input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input). [input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) converts numeric input to from string to integer.

```
>>> input()
001
1
>>> raw_input()
001
'001'
```